# Highcharts (highstock) - hide all markers in the navigator

Tags: highcharts

I have got into little trouble with hiding the markers in the navigator
The problem is that after I set marker.enabled to false. It does nothing. (JS fiddle - line 75)

```
navigator: {
    series: {
       lineWidth: 0,
       marker: {
          enabled: false // this should hide markers
       }
    }
```

}

It is doing nothing because I have some condition where if the condition is true I need to insert the marker at that point, like this:(JS fiddle - line 63).

Btw.. in that JSfiddle example I'm setting it for every point, but that doesn't matter.

```
series: [{
   data: {
      x: ...,
      y: ...,
      marker: {
         enabled: true
      }
   }
]}
```

- so when I set it manually on that point, it will override the global navigator options

**PROBLEM** - The global navigator option for the marker is overriden by every single point.

**GOAL** - Hide all markers in the navigator.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1um9gs47/3/)

<s>***OLD SOLUTION***</s>

If you have **only 1 serie** in the graph - take the Wojciech Smiel answer.

If you have **more than 1 serie** in the graph - you have to first make an array of the series with the disabled marker, and then set the options like this

```
navigator: {
   series: seriesArray // array with the series and disabled marker
}
```

**NEW SOLUTION**

My friend recently discovered better and easier solution, each serie has `navigatorOptions` property where you can set `radius` for the marker, if you set it to `0` it will be hidden.

`serie.navigatorOptions = { marker: { radius: 0 } }`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [Highcharts navigator documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.series):

> Unless data is explicitly defined on navigator.series, the data is
>   borrowed from the first series in the chart.

That's why navigator series has markers despite the fact that you disabled it in navigator options. However, you can add separate data for the navigator where you can disable marker for each point. Check the demo posted below.

Code:

```
function generateData(markers) {
  // generate an array of random data
  var data = [],
    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
    i;

  for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
    data.push({
      x: time + i * 1000,
      y: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
      marker: {
        enabled: markers
      }
    });
  }

  return data;
}

// Create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        // set up the updating of the chart each second
        var chart = this,
          series = this.series[0],
          seriesNav = this.series[1];

        setInterval(function() {
          var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
            y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

          series.addPoint([x, y], false);
          seriesNav.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
        }, 1000);

      }
    }
  },

  time: {
    useUTC: false
  },

  rangeSelector: {
    buttons: [{
      count: 1,
      type: 'minute',
      text: '1M'
    }, {
      count: 5,
      type: 'minute',
      text: '5M'
    }, {
      type: 'all',
      text: 'All'
    }],
    inputEnabled: false,
    selected: 0
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Live random data'
  },

  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      marker: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Random data',
    showInNavigator: true,
    data: generateData(true)
  }],
  navigator: {
    series: {
      lineWidth: 0,
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      },
      data: generateData(false)
    }
  }
});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1um9gs47/21/